# Only outgoing connection, no incoming connection in LAN

Tags: windows-xp, connection, lan

In one of the Windows XP PC sometimes all other Pc's in the LAN connection cannot access it.

but all the other PC's can be accessed from it.Its like no incomming connection only outgoing .

It is windows XP with SP3 .

When LAN cable is reinserted and rebooted it works fine and same issue appears again .

Comment: In what way is it being accessed?  A share?

Comment: You write "When LAN cable is reinserted and rebooted" <-- rebooting your cable?

Comment: Try safe mode(that should stop any 3rd party software firewall) and try turning off the xp firewall. The XP/7 FW and most 3rd party firewalls would typically block incoming by default.

Comment: @paul its being aceessed using share

Comment: @barlop rebooting system

Comment: @ITresearcher what if instead of rebooting, you do ipconfig /release ipconfig /renew?  or how about ctrl panel..network connections, right clicking LAN and choosing Repair

Comment: @barlop never tried.But why it happens?

Comment: @ITresearcher I have a laptop where sometimes the LAN would go wrong.. I didn't try restarting, I just did that. It fixed it usually.. not sure if it's totally dead now. Could be a hardware fault with the LAN connector/controller/circuitry on the computer. I don't know. But it's quicker to do repair or to ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew, than to restart. You could see if event viewer has anything when it goes bad. Or try to find a trigger e.g. time it on your watch(if it's set x sec then maybe software interfering). no idea what it is. just know what to do.